# Rails 5 with Docker (Unable to create app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I'm getting started with docker and following official docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/).
When I execute `docker-compose run` command only a temp folder gets created and no other folder/file.

> Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client
RUN mkdir /payment-api
WORKDIR /payment-api
COPY Gemfile /payment-api/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /payment-api/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
COPY . /payment-api

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

> Command I'm running to create the rails app

```
docker-compose run web rails new . --force --no-deps --database=postgresql
```

P.S: Not getting any sort of error and commands are executing normally but nothing except a `temp` folder gets created.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late but I faced a similar issue running Docker toolbox on a Windows 10 Home Edition , along with VirtualBox . The key here is to allow "shared folder" access to VirtualBox . Navigate to VirtualBox -> Settings -> Shared Folders . Add your application path to "Shared Folders" . It should work fine now .

Hope this helps!